# Code not dynamically updating itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js">
```

```
    $.getJSON('http://anyorigin.com/get?url=microsoftwebpro.com&callback=?', 
    function(data){
       $('#output').html(data.contents);
       $('a').each(function() {
            $(this).attr('href', 'http://anyorigin.com/get?url='+$(this).attr('href')+'&callback=?');
       });
   });
```

```
   $('a').click(function() {

     $.getJSON($(this).attr('href'), function(data) {
       $('#output').html(data.contents);
     });
  });
```

But I can't seem to figure out why it isn't loading in the right order.
So for example, I want it to load the contents from another domain, then add an add filter href to all the links in the "output" div and only that div(not working)
And then if I click a link it updates the "output" div instead of actually navigating to the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to bypass changing the `<a>` elements and just capture the clicks. Since you're dealing with dynamically created elements, it will probably be easier to use [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

```js
function AnyOriginURL(url) {
  return 'http://anyorigin.com/get?url='+url+'&callback=?';
}

function Navigate(url) {
  $.getJSON(AnyOriginURL(url), function(data){
    $('#output').html(data.contents);
  });
}

// When clicking any <a> inside the #output...
$("#output").on("click", "a", function(e) {
  // Prevent click from triggering navigation
  e.preventDefault();

  // And Navigate there using our method
  Navigate($(this).attr("href"));
});

// Onload, start at this base page
$(function() {
  Navigate("microsoftwebpro.com");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

**Take heed: When using this example, the website is very slow to load**

Comment: Would there be a reason that swf objects do not load? I right click and it says "movie not loaded"
Look here for example: http://goldandblack.doodlekit.com/home
Click on a link to a game

Comment: @CameronGilbert I imagine there are still restrictions due to the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). I wouldn't know how to prevent them; you would have to somehow capture all of the webpage's requests, which I doubt there is a way to do. Is there any reason that you're not simply using an [`<iframe>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)?

Comment: Honestly im trying to get past school website blockers, and funnel the page through multiple sites.
Not only that I want to be able to just edit the original page and use the code on different domains